# How to find max value by linqtoexcel from the column(s) of excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I would like to find maximum value(s) of excel column(s) by using linqtoexcel.

```
ColumnA ColumnB
   1       1
   2       4
   3       3
```

which will return

"max ColumnA  is 3" 
"max ColumnB  is 4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your workbook columns to POCO

```
public class WorkSheetClass
{
    public int ColumnA { get; set; }
    public int ColumnB { get; set; }
}
```

then using LinqToExcel

```
string pathToExcelFile = @"C:\workbook1.xlsx";
string workbookName = "workbook1";

var columnAMaxValue = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile)
                              .Worksheet<WorkSheetClass>(workbookName)
                              .Max(x => x.ColumnA);
```